# HighCharts issue in Google Chrome

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

In the Reputation Graph view, it is now not possible in Google Chrome to drag and view on a different time scale. Is it possible to fix the HighCharts responsible for this?

[image]

It throws a warning:

> `'webkitMovementX' is deprecated. Please use 'movementX' instead.`
>   `'webkitMovementY' is deprecated. Please use 'movementY' instead.`

**Solution**

- Upgrade to latest version of HighCharts. [*They have fixed the issue.*](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4568)
- Change all the occurrences of `webkitMovementX` to `movementX` and `webkitMovementY` to `movementY` in `HighCharts.js`.

Comment: This sounds like something for Highcharts to fix if it requires making that modification *after* updating.

Comment: @Undo This has been a problem with Chrome for ages... I am definitely sure HighCharts have already fixed it.

Comment: @Undo https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4568